# Find who created files that are not deleted

Tags: java, jvm

There are many places in my code in which temporary files are deleted and in some cases these temp files are not deleted.

Is there a way to find in Java where files were created but not deleted (similar to finding memory leaks in `C++`)?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Try an IDE like IntelliJ and search for all instances of a telltale line of code.

Comment: Are you deleting the files from within the code, using the `delete()` of `File` class?!

Comment: Yes, but seems to miss some places. There are over 300 occurrences of new File(.. so it would be hard to find the problematic places

Comment: Is the problem that the program attempts to delete the files but fails, or that the program "forgets" to delete them. If its the program forgetting why not create a manager class that keeps track of creation and deletion

Answer (score 1):

By overriding the File class you can add the opened file into a set and remove it when you delete it. That way you should be able to probe which files are opened any given Point. Not sure that's what you are looking for though.

Comment: And then you can search your entire code base to ensure that none of the raw File class are used

Comment: It might work. However it would still be a problem in case the files are created using move/copy

Answer (score 0):

It's not a "pretty" solution, but you could use a custom `SecurityManager` and look for `FilePermission`.

```
private static class FileSecurityManager extends SecurityManager {

    @Override
    public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
        if (perm instanceof FilePermission) {
            System.out.println(perm);
        }

        // super.checkPermission(perm);
    }

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setSecurityManager(new FileSecurityManager());

    Files.delete(Files.createTempFile(null, null));
    File.createTempFile("tempfile", null).delete();
}
```

This example works with standard IO and NIO access to the filesystem.